# PHP script running in the background

Tags: php, abort

Let's say I have a script that uses ignore_user_abort and set_time_limit with the value of 0, is it possible to check using php to see when that process/task has finished other than writing the result to a file or a database?

Currently I just write to a file and use a script to see if it has ended, which works, but if something goes wrong, the script may have ended already but in the file it may seem as if it is still running.

I use this format:

```
script|timestamp_start|timestamp_end\n
```

eg

```
script|10000000|0 - script runs
script|10000000|1000000001 - script ended
```

Comment: How do you _run_ this script?

Comment: I have a form that sends data to the script.

Comment: What platform is it? *nix or windows?

Comment: *nix, however the script is part of a cms that will also have to work on windows. Would getmyinode() be an option btw?

Comment: I was thinking about saving `getmypid()` in a file and doing a `system('ps 12345');` but this would be platform dependent :(

Comment: Thanks for helping though, really appreciate it!

Comment: a semaphore could help.--> http://php.net/manual/en/intro.sem.php
but i dont know if its platform dependent.
the file solution its, by far, the simplest aproach. maybe this can help: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php

Comment: Do you have access to `pcntl` or are you on a CGI build? I approach these with two different approaches, either `pcntl_fork()` and watch for `SIGCHLD` to know when it dies, or write a heartbeat every so often with some way of checking the last heartbeat timestamp against a timeout.